# Run localhost/laravel/public/my_page the result is just a blank page without any error

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a Laravel project, all pages run fine if using **php artisan serve**, but some pages **can not run without artisan serve**.
Example when I access localhost:8000/my_page my page is loaded fine. But when I run localhost/laravel/public/my_page
the result is just a blank page without any error.

Answer (score 1):

By default `localhost/laravel/public/my_page` uses port **80** but Laravel is only listening to port **8000**, `localhost:8000/my_page` works because is telling your browser to use port **8000** instead of the default port of 80.

Try running `php artisan serve --port=80` if you do not have another service already running on port 80 or if your firewall does not block the port then you should be able to use `localhost/laravel/public/my_page`

Comment: This is some pic when i use another page without artisan serve,my page loaded fine like this [link](https://imgur.com/KBIiLUF), my dashboard loaded fine on localhost:8000/dashboard [link](https://imgur.com/ReP0BBX),but when i try use localhost/blog/public/dashboard my vue component not loaded without any error [link](https://imgur.com/n4Cn9c8)

Comment: Do the Sources and Network tabs confirm that the js was loaded without errors?

Comment: Try using the [Vue Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) chrome extension to confirm that Vue is booting your vue components

Comment: It says"Vue.js not detected", any suggestion to resolve ?

Comment: Here's what I would try: (1) Make sure you built your js using `npm run dev` and not `npm run prod` otherwise Vue Dev Tools can't inspect your js. (2) Make sure that the browser is not caching the old js file (with the dev tools open, while holding shift and click on the page refresh icon and select "Empty cache and hard reload"). (3) Make sure your browser is actually loading the correct page.

Comment: Still not working [link](https://imgur.com/NyrUebp), i use this project as my dashboard page [link](https://github.com/jcc/blog). I'm tired of this, maybe I should make a new project, btw thanks for your help sir.